# Calling Javascript function after loading an AJAX page

Tags: php, javascript, css, ajax, siblings

I'm not a programmer so I apologize if my question doesn't make a lot of sense.

But basically I have one page index.php that has a set of filters (by project, year, month) and after pressing submit sends the variables to filterData.php to be used in some SQL statements.

The results in the form of a table of image thumbnails are returned to a div in index.php. What I want to do is have it so when the user clicks on an image the border color will change to highlight the current object.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.thumbnail_small').click(function(){
        $(this)
            .css('border-color','#000')
            .siblings()
            .css('border-color','#ccc');
    });
});
</script>
```

^ That is the script I have right now and it works if the table of thumbnails is hardcoded into index.php. Once I have the table loaded through filterData.php, it doesn't work anymore.

What is the reason for this and how can I work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Once I have the table loaded through filterData.php, it doesn't work
>   anymore.

Use [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or better [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) depending on version of jQuery you are using:

```
$('#mainContainer').on('click', '.thumbnail_small', function(){
    $(this)
        .css('border-color','#000')
        .siblings()
        .css('border-color','#ccc');
});
```

Or

```
$('.thumbnail_small').live('click', function(){
    $(this)
        .css('border-color','#000')
        .siblings()
        .css('border-color','#ccc');
});
```

For elements that are added later or dynamically, you got to use `live` or `on`.

Comment: Is #mainContainer the parent div? I am using Jquery 1.3 and this is what I changed it to but it's still not working: <br/><script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#box_left').on('click', '.thumbnail_small', function(){
    $(this)
        .css('border-color','#000')
        .siblings()
        .css('border-color','#ccc');
});
});
</script>

Comment: @user1067577: Yes you should have a container with id to that eg `id="mainContainer"` you can change its name or use existing one. Or you can simply use second example in my answer.

Comment: You are amazing!! Thank you so much :) I used the second example.