# Javascript sibling onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, onclick, siblings

This is related to a question I've asked previously: [Calling Javascript function after loading an AJAX page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556200/calling-javascript-function-after-loading-an-ajax-page)

Basically, before all the thumbnails were loaded dynamically into one container called #left_box. Using the script below, I can get it to highlight one div out of all the siblings.

```
$('.thumbnail_small').live('click', function(){
    $(this)
        .css('border-color','#000')
        .siblings()
        .css('border-color','#ccc');
});
```

However, in order to accommodate a new feature, I had to split the thumbnails into even more containers called `.contain`. Basically `#left_box` contains a series of `.contain` that hold x number of thumbnails. Now when I click on a thumbnail in one `.contain`, it only affects the siblings within that container rather than the larger container `#left_box`.

I tried

```
$('#left_box').on('click', '.thumbnail_small', function(){
    $(this)
        .css('border-color','#000')
        .siblings()
        .css('border-color','#ccc');
});
```

but it doesn't work. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: think you need to post your html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest repeating your seletor, using the [not](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method to exclude the current element:

```
$('#left_box').on('click', '.thumbnail_small', function(){
    $(this).css('border-color','#000');
    $('#left_box .thumbnail_small').not(this).css('border-color','#ccc');
});
```

This will select all `.thumbnail_small` inside your `#left_box`, exclude the clicked one, then applying the css to the rest of them.

Comment: i tried that and then tweaked it a little to get: `code` $('.thumbnail_small').live('click', function(){
  $(this).css('border-color','#717171');
  $('#box_left .thumbnail_small').not(this).css('border-color','#ccc');
 });`code` and it works. thanks!